# Prevent client from calling server-side methods

Tags: meteor

so I have a login form that accepts a username and password. When a username/password is entered and submit is clicked, the first step is to check if the account exists and is enabled. I've accomplished that using the code below. The problem is, the server-side method that does the checking, `is_user_enabled`, can be accessed by the client via the browser console. Usually I can prevent this by doing:

```
my_method : function(doc) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        // Only admins can run this method.
    }
}
```

But in the case of `is_user_enabled`, the user is not logged in yet. So, my question is, what is the correct way to handle this situation?

My code:

**client/login.html**

```
{{#autoForm schema=get_login_form_schema id="login_form"}}
    {{> flashMessages}}
    <fieldset>
        <!-- <legend>Create User</legend> -->
        {{> afQuickField name="username" placeholder="schemaLabel" label=false}}
        {{> afQuickField name="password" placeholder="schemaLabel" type="password" label=false}}
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
{{/autoForm}}
```

**client/lib/helpers.js**

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    login_form: {
        onSubmit: function (insert_doc, update_doc, current_doc) {
            Meteor.call("is_user_enabled", insert_doc, function(error, result) {
                if (result) {
                   // Try to log user in via Meteor.loginWithPassword()
                 }
            });
         }
    }
});
```

**server/lib/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    is_user_enabled : function(doc) {
        // Used by the login form. Returns true if user exists and account is enabled.
        check(doc, schemas.login);
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: doc.username}, {fields: {status: 1}});
        if (user.status === "enabled") {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

**Final Solution**:

**client/lib/helpers.js**

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    login_form: {
        onSubmit: function (insert_doc, update_doc, current_doc) {
            Meteor.loginWithPassword(insert_doc.username, insert_doc.password, function(error) {
                // Called with no arguments on success
                // or with a single Error argument on failure.
                if (error) {
                    FlashMessages.sendError(error);
                    this.done();
                } else {
                    // Successful login. Redirect to /.
                    this.done();
                    Router.go('/');
                }
            });
            return false;  // Prevent browser submit event.
        },
    }
```

**server/lib/permissions.js**

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (info) {
    if (info.user && info.user.status === "enabled") {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error("Invalid credentials.");
    }
});
```

More info about `[Accounts.validateLoginAttempt][1]`

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent the client from calling a server method. Your checks for *is_user_enabled* and *is_admin* need to happen inside your server methods as well as on the client. You can of course have private functions inside your methods.js file that only methods on the server can access. For more tips see http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/07/meteor-security-no-1-meteorcall.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you *can* prevent Meteor methods from being executed from the client side. this.connection will only be set inside a method when it is called from the client. When called from the server it will be null. The enables you to do something like this:

```
serverOnlyMethod: function () {
    if(this.connection) throw(new Meteor.Error(403, 'Forbidden.'));
}
```